# Is there a Scala equivalent of petapoco?

Tags: c#, scala, orm

I'm learning SCALA, and haven't been able to find a simple Scala "micro-ORM" that I like. I'm looking for something very light weight like petapoco (http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/).  The closest thing I could find is anorm, but it seems to require that you instruct it on how to map to/from the database.

In petapoco, I can do this:

```
foreach (var a in db.Query<article>("SELECT * FROM articles"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1}", a.article_id, a.title);
}
```

Or (even better in cases where I don't have a class, but want to pass straight through to Json):

```
return Json(db.Query<dynamic>("Select name, id From people"));
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where have you looked, and what have you checked out? There's one big question about this on Stack Overflow (the first one in the "Related" links), as well as as a bunch of different alternatives on [the wiki](https://wiki.scala-lang.org/display/SW/Tools+and+Libraries#ToolsandLibraries-DataStorage). And, to be honest, if what you want isn't there, then it probably doesn't exist at all.

Comment: Dern.  I guess it doesn't really exist, then. :(

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) (a java lightweight ORM) or [Squeryl](http://squeryl.org/). Not sure if either of those support transforming a query result to Json directly. Another alternative would be [lift mapper](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/Mapper). If you go with that transforming to json would be fairly straightforward using lifts json capabilities.

Comment: Thanks, Emil.  The Json function isn't part of petapoco, but serves to illustrate that there are scenarios where I don't want to have to define an object or manual mapping of values, just pass straight through to an external processor (in this case, MVC's json function).

Comment: That is how it's done with lift-json. You define a case class and you can map between it and a json string. Checkout http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/JSON_Support for a more detailed explanation.